# When writing a Bash script, how do I create then open a file with the date as part of the name?

Tags: bash, scripts, vim, automation

I want to use a script to open a list of URLs, then create an empty text-file called "[today's date].homework" and then open that text file in Vim.
Here's the script I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash
## Open firefox to the websites containing each classes' homework assignments.
firefox -new-window -url https://www.firsturl.com -new-tab -url https://www.secondurl.com -new-tab -url http://www.thirdurl.com -new-tab -url https://www.fourthurl.com -new-tab -url https://www.fifthurl.com
## Set up today's date as prefix for the filename.
today=`date '+%Y_%m_%d'`;
filename="~/homework/today.homework"
## Open the created file in Vim.
vim ~/homework/today.homework
```

The purpose of this script is to open all of the places that contain my homework assignments, then open a date-stamped file for me to manually input the day's assignments. I want to manually type the assignments rather than use `curl` or `wget` because I need to remember the assignments and typing them manually is the best way to do that. In addition, I've only been using Linux for 6 weeks and I think that automating the compilation process with those tools is a little out of my depth.
Also, is there a way to have it automatically run each time I log in each day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line for `today=` should look like this:

```
today=$(date +%Y_%m_%d)
```

since `today` is now a variable, it would be designated with a `$` leading the word like this:

```
echo $today
```

which would give `2016_02_23` as the output.  So, the lines after using that `today` variable would look like this:

```
filename="~/homework/${today}.homework"
```

and

```
vim "~/homework/${today}.homework"
```

or since you gave `filename` as a variable then you could do this:

```
vim "$filename"
```

Or, if you want to really get creative, instead of assigning the variable first, you can just do the command itself in the filename when you're opening it all in one line:

```
vim "~/homework/$(date +%Y_%m_%d).homework"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works perfectly! I didn't know that `$` designated a variable. 
Also, thank you for correcting my typo. Edited!

Comment: I would recommend to use `${today}.homework` in this case. `$variable` and `${variable}` are exactly the same, but `${variable}` also works when you embed the variable into a string without surrounding it with non-variable name characters like the `.`. You would need it for e.g. file name patterns like `python${today}homework`.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yep, that works too!  Variable expansion is a great habit to get into, when you remember to use it.  Thank you for the edit!  =)

Comment: @user510782 You are very welcome!  I also edited my answer to include variable expansion that ByteCommander edited, and also a one liner for your filename with built-in variable.